# JPA Multiple Embedded fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

Is it possible for a JPA entity class to contain two embedded (`@Embedded`) fields? An example would be:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Embedded
    public Address home;

    @Embedded
    public Address work;
}

public class Address {
    public String street;
    ...
}
```

In this case a `Person` can contain two `Address` instances - home and work. I'm using JPA with Hibernate's implementation. When I generate the schema using Hibernate Tools, it only embeds one `Address`. What I'd like is two embedded `Address` instances, each with its column names distinguished or pre-pended with some prefix (such as home and work). I know of `@AttributeOverrides`, but this requires that each attribute be individually overridden. This can get cumbersome if the embedded object (`Address`) gets big as each column needs to be individually overridden.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to have the same embeddable object type twice in the same entity, the column name defaulting will not work: at least one of the columns will have to be explicit. Hibernate goes beyond the EJB3 spec and allows you to enhance the defaulting mechanism through the NamingStrategy. DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy is a small improvement over the default EJB3NamingStrategy that allows embedded objects to be defaulted even if used twice in the same entity.

From Hibernate Annotations Doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e714

Answer (score 89):

The generic JPA way to do it is with @AttributeOverride. This should work in both EclipseLink and Hibernate.

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(name="homeStreet")),
    ...
  })
  @Embedded public Address home;

  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(name="workStreet")),
    ...
  })
  @Embedded public Address work;
  }

  @Embeddable public class Address {
    @Basic public String street;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `name="street"` refers to the name of the property, not the column name.

Comment: Is this considered "clunky," as it requires the developer of Person to know intimate things about the class Address (like the name of the field containing the street name)?

Comment: wow, so i have to repeat it all using annotations. wtf. i could just as well declare the entire  embedded class myself manually using String homeStreet; String workStreeet instead, probably more deterministic.

Comment: @mmm Before you "wtf" you might take the time to get aware of the different contexts you're in. Why would you want to create a dedicated FooAddress class for every foo you might have in the referring entity?

Comment: @Amadán for me, to avoid redundancy. Having to redeclare the rules of Adress related stuff over and over again. Unfortunately Hibernate does not offer great ways to do that.

Comment: @mbmast Your team may find it intuitive to have a 1:1 mapping of database table to Entity classes. Your DBAs already decided that homeStreet should be denormalized and on the Person table.

Comment: @mmm TIMTOWDI, there are often cleaner solutions in a greenfields environment. OP may have had lots of existing legacy code using person.home.street that they can't change.

Answer (score 6):

When using Eclipse Link, an alternative to using AttributeOverrides it to use a SessionCustomizer. This solves the issue for all entities in one go:

```
public class EmbeddedFieldNamesSessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
    Map<Class, ClassDescriptor> descriptors = session.getDescriptors();
    for (ClassDescriptor classDescriptor : descriptors.values()) {
        for (DatabaseMapping databaseMapping : classDescriptor.getMappings()) {
            if (databaseMapping.isAggregateObjectMapping()) {
                AggregateObjectMapping m = (AggregateObjectMapping) databaseMapping;
                Map<String, DatabaseField> mapping = m.getAggregateToSourceFields();

                ClassDescriptor refDesc = descriptors.get(m.getReferenceClass());
                for (DatabaseMapping refMapping : refDesc.getMappings()) {
                    if (refMapping.isDirectToFieldMapping()) {
                        DirectToFieldMapping refDirectMapping = (DirectToFieldMapping) refMapping;
                        String refFieldName = refDirectMapping.getField().getName();
                        if (!mapping.containsKey(refFieldName)) {
                            DatabaseField mappedField = refDirectMapping.getField().clone();
                            mappedField.setName(m.getAttributeName() + "_" + mappedField.getName());
                            mapping.put(refFieldName, mappedField);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: +1 Would be nice to have this as a DescriptorCustomizer, to be able to control this per class, but I haven't found a way to access the ClassDescriptor of the embedded class from within the DescriptorCustomizer of the host class.

Comment: The alternative I'm using now is to check `classDescriptor.getJavaClass()` in the SessionCustomizer against a list of classes I want it to affect.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using hibernate you can also use a different naming scheme which adds unique prefixes to columns for identical embedded fields. See [Automatically Add a Prefix to Column Names for @Embeddable Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046677/automatically-add-a-prefix-to-column-names-for-embeddable-classes/43018343#43018343)