# Embeddable with custom UserType used twice in entity

Tags: hibernate, annotations, embeddable

I'm using `@Embeddable` `REmbeddedReference` twice in my entity `RTask`. This embeddable contains QName property which type is defined as `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`.

```
@Embeddable
public class REmbeddedReference implements Serializable {

    private String targetOid;
    private String description;
    private String filter;
    private RContainerType type;
    private QName relation;

    @Columns(columns = {
            @Column(name = "relation_namespace"),
            @Column(name = "relation_localPart")
    })
    public QName getRelation() {        return relation;    }

    @Column(length = 36, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)
    public String getTargetOid() {        return targetOid;    }

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    public String getDescription() {        return description;    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    public RContainerType getType() {        return type;    }

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    public String getFilter() {        return filter;    }

    ...setters...
}
```

`RTask` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_task")
public class RTask extends RObject {
    private REmbeddedReference objectRef;
    private REmbeddedReference ownerRef;
    ...other fields...

    @Embedded
    public REmbeddedReference getObjectRef() {
        return objectRef;
    }

    @Embedded
    public REmbeddedReference getOwnerRef() {
        return ownerRef;
    }

    ...other methods...
}
```

During startup I get:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.evolveum.midpoint.repo.sql.data.common.RTask column: relation_namespace (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

I tried to update my NamingStrategy, method logicalColumnName which generated objectRef_relation_namespace and ownerRef_relation_namespace. But then I get:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [m_task] contains phyical column name [relation_namespace] represented by different logical column names: [objectRef_relation_namespace], [ownerRef_relation_namespace]`

Do you have any idea how to map property `relation` in `REmbeddedReference` properly?

Comment: Get an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331744/jpa-multiple-embedded-fields

Comment: I know about `DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy` but when I remove `@Columns` from `REmbeddedReference` then I get: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.evolveum.midpoint.repo.sql.data.common.RTask.objectRef type: component[description,filter,relation,targetOid,type]` because that QName (custom user type) field `relation` has to be represented with two columns...

Comment: Your embeddable has column definitions.  Obviously, you can't have two columns with the same name in a table.  Look at the second post in the link provided.  You should be able to use @AttributeOverride to name the columns appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
@AttributeOverride(name="relation.namespace", column=@Column(name="object_namespace")
@AttributeOverride(name="relation.localPart", column=@Column(name="object_localpart")
@Embedded
public REmbeddedReference getObjectRef() {
    return objectRef;
}

@AttributeOverride(name="relation.namespace", column=@Column(name="owner_namespace")
@AttributeOverride(name="relation.localPart", column=@Column(name="owner_localpart")
@Embedded
public REmbeddedReference getOwnerRef() {
    return ownerRef;
}
```

didn't work. I had to change `QName` type implementation from `CompositeUserType` to another embeddable entity `RQName` which represents this property in `REmbeddedReference` embeddable.