# Repeated column in mapping entity

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using in my project JPA embedded entities. I have this embeddable class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

And I am embedding this class in here:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements DomainObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Embedded
    private Address billingAddress;

    @Embedded
    private Address shippingAddress;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

After running the project, I got following error:

**Repeated column in mapping entity:

theo.tziomakas.udemy.domain.Customer column: billing_address_line1 (should be mapped with insert = "false" update = "false"**

How can I fix this error?

---

*You can clone my [project](https://github.com/theo82/SpringJPA) if you want and check it yourself. I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076463/another-repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-error) answer, but didn't get anything.*

Comment: Can you post your Database Schema?

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya. Is this necessary? I can't at the moment.

Comment: How do you store `billingAddress` in your Database? Is it flat or is it a JSON? Also, if it is flat, what are the database column names you have assigned to it? Is it the exact same as `Address`?

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya. Ιt's flat. Yes the columns are the same as Address.

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya. But right now I store nothing, as I get the described exception. But you can clone and run the project to have a better idea!

Comment: Ok it's fixed now. I will post the answer later in the evening. Thank you for spending some time for helping solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I cloned your repository and found that the problem arises because you have Embedded Address 2 times - `shippingAddress` and `billingAddress` in `Customer.java`
. I would recommend the using `@AttributeOverride` annotation to solve this issue. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331744/jpa-multiple-embedded-fields).

Change the Entity Fields like this.

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="addressLine1",column=@Column(name="billingAddressLine1")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="addressLine2",column=@Column(name="billingAddressLine2")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="billingCity")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state",column=@Column(name="billingState")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zipCode",column=@Column(name="billingZipCode")),
})
private Address billingAddress;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="addressLine1",column=@Column(name="shippingAddressLine1")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="addressLine2",column=@Column(name="shippingAddressLine2")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="shippingCity")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state",column=@Column(name="shippingState")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zipCode",column=@Column(name="shippingZipCode")),
})
private Address shippingAddress;
```